# Python Webshop for Retailers / Distributors

Tags: python, django, webshop

I have an internal request from sales in my organisation to build a webshop for our distributors/retailers. I wonder if there is a webshop that does this built on Python/Django?

I find it much more complex than a normal web-shop because of this:

1. Customers become set into groups - A,B,C
2. A group has discounts on a product depending on how much they buy of each product, lets say 
   1-100 pieces: 4 USD
   101-200 pieces: 5 USD

But another group gets a totally different price.

Mathematically this becomes a factorial problem with combinations, so the possible combinations of a customer - price per selected amount of items - group - product immediately becomes huge.

My guess is that it is best to do something like this:
1. Set our buying price for a product
2. Add a minimum margin for each amounts of purchases: 1-100 and so on. This way no customer can get lower than we at least make a profit.
3. Then depending on what group the customer belongs to, add another margin on top of 1 & 2.
4. Display The product on a webpage with the different prices when they add different amounts of items in the basket.

That creates prices built on calculations instead of a fixed price list, but it should work?

Is there anyone out there that has a working FOSS webshop in Python for this? Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

[mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) looks like a great project to look at it uses [Cartridge](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Cartridge) for it's Shopping cart module. They have a really nice [demo site](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/blog/?t=13540978075) that you can use as and end user and and admin to edit products and prices. Django packages also have an [eCommerce page](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/ecommerce/) worth looking at that evaluates a whole bunch of django packages on different features. I'm sure with those two resources you'll find something worth using as a base at least.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [**Satchmo**](http://www.satchmoproject.com/)?

Satchmo has support for [user-group based discounts](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/pricing.html#pricing-tiers):

> Satchmo supports setting different price and discount tiers based on
>   user groups. The most common reason a store owner may need this is if
>   they want to offer different discounts or prices for a class of user.
>   For instance, a user with a “Gold” membership may automatically get a
>   percentage discount. Another common usage is for wholesale versus
>   retail pricing.

and the discounts may be activated when a [certain quantity is ordered](http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/discounts.html):

> On the product variations, the price can have an expiration date and/or a quantity. If either of these fields are set then that price is only effective for orders placed before that date, or >= that quantity.

Satchmo is also widely used, so the documentation and the community is good.